# How to add Relay QL value to isomorphic relay router

Tags: reactjs, router, graphql, relayjs

My application need support for localization. I am using isomorphic relay router.

```
const customQueries = {
  viewer: () => Relay.QL'
  fragment on JobSeekerEntry{
      language
  }
  '
};

export default [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: Index,
        queries: ViewerQueries,
        indexRoute: {
            component: Home,
            onEnter: ({params}, replace) => replace("/" + customQueries.viewer.lanaguage  ),
            queries: ViewerQueries,
            prepareParams: () => ({status: 'any'}),
        },
        childRoutes: [
            {
                path: "/:language",
                component: Home,
                queries: ViewerQueries,

            },
            {
                path: "/:language/status",
                component: Test,
                queries: ViewerQueries,

            },
            {
                path: '/:language/test/:user',
                component: Home,
                queries: ViewerQueries,
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

In the above code sample is want  user to redirect according to his/her preffered lanaguage. For SEO support I want to display www.exmaple.com/en for english and www.example.com/jp for japanese etc. "en" and "jp" values are come from graphql (from server). I want to assign those values as a router param. Specially when page renders from server side. Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `ViewerQueires` as a constant and pass language as params like this

```
const ViewerQueries = {
  viewer: () => Relay.QL `query{post(postID: $language)}`,
};
```

And you should define fragment on Component page as below

```
export default Relay.createContainer(Home, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on JobSeekerEntry {
        language
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Comment: Please show your schema.js for more accurate answer.